# Can I travel to Kuwait on a visa with old passport number?

Tags: visas, passports, kuwait, passport-renewals

I have a Kuwait visa, obtained from a hotel in Kuwait, with my old passport number. But as the validity of the present passport is expiring within 6 months, I got a new passport with a new passport number. Can I travel with the same visa or do I have to obtain a new visa with my new passport number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Valid UK Visa in an Expired Passport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49187/valid-uk-visa-in-an-expired-passport)

Answer (score 7):

Bring the old passport with you along with your new passport (hopefully you still have it) and you will be able to enter. This applies to all other countries provided that the page where the visa is not cancelled (usually by writing a big X or by puncturing it in the sides).

Update: Always remember to ask the authority to handle you the old passport when you renew it and do not forget to mark the valid visas page before renewal as @Jonas commented.

Comment: @A.K.Sing: If your country invalidates passports by puncturing, it's very important to mark the pages that are not to be destroyed, e.g. by folding a marked sheet of paper over them that is larger than the passport.

Comment: In The Netherlands, you can only get a new passport by handing in the old one.

Comment: @HaLaBi Yes, according to the *Paspoortuitvoeringsregeling Nederland 2001*, [article 67](http://wetten.overheid.nl/BWBR0012811/HoofdstukVIII/i1/Artikel67/geldigheidsdatum_12-01-2013). However, when there are still valid visa and the passport user asks explicitly, the passport is invalidated in such a way that the document number and the visa are still visible. By default, however, the old passport is burned.