# Valid UK Visa in an Expired Passport

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, passport-renewals

I have a valid (multiple entry) business visit visa to the UK on my old passport. I have recently obtained a new passport as I ran out of pages on my old passport. The purpose of my visit is still for business and there are no change in personal details on my new passport. There is however a change in address on the new passport. Incidentally it is the same address that I filled out for my UK visa application while answering the query "WHAT IS YOUR PERMANENT RESIDENTIAL ADDRESS AND CONTACT DETAILS?"

In light of the above, can I still travel to the UK by carrying both the old and new passports? Or, will I be required to either transfer the visa or make a fresh application for my new passport. Thanks.

Comment: I have an indefinite leave to stay stamp on my old (expired) passport and I just carry my old and new one and present them both at the time of entry. Its been 5 years and I have traveled to UK 6-7 times since without a problem. I am not sure how it works with other types of visas.

Answer (score 4):

They will allow you to use the visa in your old passport if it is the one issued immediately prior to your new passport.  They will usually mark your new passport with "VIPP" (Visa In Prior Passport).

> You don’t have to transfer your visa - you can carry both your old and
>   new passports when travelling to or from the UK instead.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/transfer-visa

You did not provide the amount of unspent leave on your visa, but if it is longer than 90 days, they may require you to get a [transfer of conditions](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/application-to-transfer-visa-to-biometric-residence-permit-form-toc) during your next visit.  This is a very straight-forward process which does not include the assessment and decision-making that happens during a visa application.

Finally, regarding your change of address, if you want to play it *strictly by the book* you can prepare a change of circumstances notice and present it to the Immigration Officer at your landing interview when you arrive.